# How do I forcefully clean a field and redisplay it in Django?

Tags: python, django

How can I clean the data in a form and have the cleaned data  redisplayed instead of the submitted data?

There are several fields in my form, and every time the user submits it, it should be redisplayed with the values the user entered. However, some of the fields I would like to clean and update for the user. More specifically, I have a field `FriendlyIntegerField(forms.CharField)` in which I override `to_python` to not only call `int(str(value))`, but also set any negative number to 0 etc. I do not want to redisplay the form with the invalid data and have the user fix it himself (which is how Django wants me to do it).

I don't have a problem cleaning the data and use it for the rest of my view-function, but how can I update the actual form with this data?

By the way, the form does not reflect a structure in my data model, and so inherits from `Form`, not `ModelForm`.

**Edit:**

My Field (in a stripped down version) looks like this:

`class FriendlyIntegerField(forms.CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            return str(int(str(value).replace(' ','')))
        except:
            raise forms.ValidationError('some error msg')`

My Form (in a stripped down version) looks like this:

`class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    price_from = FriendlyIntegerField()
    price_to = FriendlyIntegerField()`

And my view:

`def search(request, key):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.REQUEST)
        if not form.is_valid():
            print "Form not valid"
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    return render_to_response('path_to_template', {'form' : form}`

Comment: As a side note, you should take care with this. I can't remember where I read it, but apparently changing the values a user has inputted can become confusing for the end-user. Simply telling them negative values aren't allowed and redisplaying their (faulty) input can prove to be more user-friendly than you might have imagined.

Comment: I absolutely agree LaundroMat. Silently changing user input is generally not a good idea. Negative numbers is maybe not the best example, and I might skip that in the final version. I do however want to remove spaces in the numbers. The field represents a price, and I think it is a good idea to automatically change "250 000" to "250000".

Answer (score 0):

If, after you've cleaned your form with `is_valid()`, you render that cleaned form with your view, rather than redirect to a new page, you'll see the cleaned data in your page.

(If you wanted the user to see this cleaned data and then properly submit it, you could use a hidden field to track whether the form data has already been cleaned, but this isn't without complications...)

Comment: Are you sure the cleaned data is supposed to be rendered when the form is redisplayed, and not the original data? I have posted a stripped down version of my code above, and would really appreciate if you could have a look and check if you can see why the cleaned data is not rendered. As an example, if I input a number with a space in it, like "42 43", I would expect it to render as "4243" based on what you are saying here, but it still renders as "42 43"

Comment: Fix it in the clean_foo(self) method and remember to return your cleaned value at the end of it. Hacking to_python is not the appropriate place if you want to clean data  (and show the effect of cleaning)

Comment: Ok, I changed to using a regular CharField, and do the cleaning in SearchForm.clean_price_from(), which returns the cleaned value. My view is the same as above, except that I log form.cleaned_data['price_from'] right before 'else'. The logged data is cleaned, the redisplayed form is not.

Comment: Also, browsing through Django's source code, it doesn't seem to follow that the cleaned data should be redisplayed. This is my understanding of django/form/forms.py: A bound form has a BoundField, which is initialized from the form's original field. When the BoundField is rendered, the data used as the value is extracted from the datadict in the original field, not from self.cleaned_data. I can not see the original field being updated from self.cleaned_data any place either.

Comment: @knatten you are right, you can find a workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662848/disabled-field-is-not-passed-through-workaround-needed/4664866#4664866)